# Как изменить переменную JS прямо на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<b>Прочитано страниц</b>: <span id="pagesJS1"></span>
```

и в подключенном `JS`

```
pagesJS1 = 462; 
document.getElementById("pagesJS1").innerHTML = pagesJS1;
```

Как изменять эту переменную не в коде, а прямо с сайта? Например, возле числа нажать на "изменить" и ввести новое число в появившееся окно. И переменная изменится. Важно, чтобы переменная сохранялась, чтобы при обновлении страницы на экране было измененное число.  И реально ли это сделать?

Comment: Вешать обработчик события onclick на кнопку. Это описано в любом учебнике по js, найдите учебник по вкусу и читайте

Comment: с обработчиком то все понятно, как изменить переменную при этом, чтобы при обновлении страницы изменение сохранилось..

Comment: Про "при обновлении страницы" - это крайне важное уточнение, которое обязательно должно присутствовать прямо в тексте вопроса

Comment: Видимо да, не думал... возможно через LS эту проблему можно решить..

Comment: Тем не менее непонятно, где именно вы хотите сохранить число. В браузере пользователя? В базе данных на сервере? К чему должно относиться это число - к браузерной сессии, к учётной записи к пользователя, к ip-адресу или это число общее для всех пользователей сайта? Должно ли число забываться, когда пользователь закрывает браузер? В общем, непонятно, что именно вы хотите

Comment: Число хранится у пользователя, не на сервере, и не в БД. Число общее для всех. Число не должно забываться.

Comment: Эм, если число хранится у пользователя, то другие пользователи увидеть его не смогут в принципе. Если число общее для всех, то хранить его на сервере в БД - единственно возможный вариант

Comment: кста твой пост навёл на вопрос. Что действительно нельзя считать куки пользователя и потом post на сервер, который обновит базу или я чё то туплю...

Comment: @user184868 а потом каждый начнет обновлять базу своими числами...

Comment: ну есть ещё такие фичи как шифрование или защита от ddos но чел в этом топе просто спросил про возможность а ты сразу не смогут в принципе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD:**

Чтобы значение переменной не менялось после обновления страницы, её надо где-то хранить. В идеале - на сервере (тогда она будет доступна для всех, кто обращается к странице).

На клиенте можно использовать localstorage (если его поддерживает браузер), но это решение только для конкретного пользователя и конкретного браузера, в котором он открывает страницу - другие пользователи изменений не увидят (*и здесь не работает - скопируйте код на свою страницу*):

```js
var pagesJS1 = localStorage.getItem("pageNum"); //передаём в переменную значение pageNum из локального хранилища
if(pagesJS1 == "") { //если хранилище пустое, то записываем в span 462
  document.getElementById("pagesJS1").innerHTML = '462';
}
else { //если там есть значение, то записываем его
  document.getElementById("pagesJS1").innerHTML = pagesJS1;
}

var btn = document.getElementById("button");
var input = document.getElementById("changeNum");

btn.onclick = function() {
  input.style.display = 'inline';
}

input.onkeyup = function() {
  var newNum = +input.value;
  localStorage.setItem("pageNum",newNum); //сохраняем в localstorage новое значение
  document.getElementById("pagesJS1").innerHTML = newNum;
}
```

```css
#changeNum {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<b>Прочитано страниц</b>: <span id="pagesJS1"></span>
<button id="button">Изменить</button>
<input type="number" id="changeNum" />
```

Comment: Все работает, однако он просто выводит измененное число на экран. Переменная то сама не меняется, в результате при обновлении страницы все вернется обратно не учитывая изменения.

Comment: @user278370, обновил ответ